# NodeJS MSSQL .query returning double data in both recordsets and recordset

Tags: sql-server, json, node.js

I'm seeing all data rows repeated twice in my JSON returned from mssql in Node:

```
{
        "recordsets": [[{
                    "student_firstname": "Jonah                ",
                    "student_lastname": "Hill                    "
                }, {
                    "student_firstname": "Debra                   ",
                    "student_lastname": "Smith               "
                }
            ]],
        "recordset": [{
                "student_firstname": "Jonah                ",
                "student_lastname": "Hill                    "
            }, {
                "student_firstname": "Debra                   ",
                "student_lastname": "Smith               "
            }
        ],
        "output": {},
        "rowsAffected": [2]
    }
```

I temporarily changed the query to get two rows to see if all rows would be duplicate, and they are as you can see above.

```
function getStudent(studentID) 
{
    console.log("---------getStudent"); 


    sql.on('error', err => {
        // ... error handler 
        console.log("DB Error2: " + err); 
    })


    return sql.connect(config).then(pool => {
            // Query 
            return pool.request()
            .input('input_parameter', sql.Int, studentID)
            //.query('select student_firstname, student_lastname from students where student_id = @input_parameter')
            .query('select student_firstname, student_lastname from students where student_id in (31,32)')
        }).then(function(result) {
            console.log("getStudent:then(result=>"); 
            console.dir(result);
            sql.close(); 
            return result; 
        })
        .catch(err => {
            // ... error checks 
            console.log("DB Error1: " + err); 
            sql.close(); 
            throw err; 
        })

}
```

The above function is called in an app.get statement that returns the JSON.

The console.dir(result) shows the same as the JSON above, except shows "[Object]: in the first line.  SO I don't think it's wrapping the JSON further.

```
{ recordsets: [ [ [Object], [Object] ] ],
  recordset:
   [ { student_firstname: 'Jonah                  ',
       student_lastname: 'Hill                    ' },
     { student_firstname: 'Debra                   ',
       student_lastname: 'Smith                   ' } ],
  output: {},
  rowsAffected: [ 2 ] }
```

I can work with the data like this, but it's wasting bandwidth.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The data is not retuned twice but just exposed through two properties. The `recordset` property just exposes the first recordset in `recordsets`.

[mssql documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#execute-procedure-callback):

```
result.recordsets.length // count of recordsets returned by the procedure
result.recordsets[0].length // count of rows contained in first recordset
result.recordset // first recordset from result.recordsets
```

Comment: But the data is wasting bytes because it is in the JSON twice.  So this is normal?  Seems very odd to me.

Comment: @NealWalters, From this answer's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51164724/sql-server-returning-results-twice-on-a-single-call/51164993#51164993). Object will only have a single reference in memory, even though it appears in two properties. I guess when the data is sent back to nodejs. there is only one set of data. nodejs just transform the data to two properties but the reference to the same object in memory. Therefore, there is no waste of memory actually.

Answer (score 5):

You can get the columns data with queries like:

```
result.recordset[0].student_firstname  // returns the value of the student firstname of first row
result.recordset[0].student_lastname   // returns the value of the student lastname of first row
```

Comment: I've moved on to other things; but I think the point of my question is why it's returning double of everything; not how to access it.

Answer (score 2):

instead of

```
console.dir(result);
```

try:

```
console.dir(result.recordsets);
```

Comment: I used res.send(recordset.recordsets[0]);   and it was OK