# SQL Server returning results twice on a single call?

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, express

I have connected a SQL Server database to a simple node.js server. When I run the code I get both recordsets and recordset returned to me. They both essentially contain the same data. I can work with this but it seems redundant and would be neater to just call exactly the records I need.

I was hoping to get an clear ELI5 explanation as `mssql` npm documentation is somewhat confusing in my opinion.

Here is the code below:

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const sql = require('mssql');
const app = express();
const sqlServer = 'hasea\\SQLExpress'

const selectAllQuery = 'SELECT * FROM dbo.users';
const config = {
    user: 'nbar',
    password: 'nb',
    server: sqlServer,
    database: 'nirvanaBar'
}

// SQL Select function
function DBconn(query, res) {

    sql.connect(config, function (err) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        var request = new sql.Request();

        request.query(query, function (err, row) {
            if (err) console.log(err)
            res.json({
                data: row
            })
        })
    })
}
app.use(cors());

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send("Hello from the server")
});

app.get('/users', (req, res) => {
    //query?
    //var andrew = "select * from dbo.users where firstName = 'Andrew';"
    var matt = "select * from dbo.users where firstName = 'Matt';"
    //DBconn(selectAllQuery,res);
    DBconn(matt, res);

})
app.listen(4000, () => {
    console.log(`Server started on port 4000`)
})
```

The results:

[image]

I can see this has being brought up before but I am not understanding what is going on nor does the documentation provide much information as to why this would be the case. I can use the data, I just thought it would be neater to return both recordsets and recordset.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the expected behaviour of mssql have a look at the documentation [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#query-command-callback). When you execute multiple statements it allows you to have multiple recordsets

You will notice that there is in fact 2 properties

recordset (singular)
and 
recordsets (plural)

recordset (singular) refers to the first statement that is executed. In your case you can just use this

recordsets (plural) is an array of recordsets, in your case there will only be one in the array as you are only running one statement.

Comment: Just to be clear I have no way to avoid this and it isn't using more resources to call that plural and singular. I am reading the documentations but not completely understanding it.

Comment: You are correct it will not be using more resources as the SQL Command is the same and the object will only have a single reference in memory, even though it appears in two properties.